# Spring MVC @ModelAttribute Case insensitive

Tags: java, spring-mvc, data-binding, modelattribute

I have the following method in my controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public RedirectView search(@ModelAttribute DeepLinkUrl deepLinkUrl) {
  // method logic goes here
}
```

DeepLinkUrl POJO class

```
 public class DeepLinkUrl{
    private String promoCode;
  public String getPromoCode() {
    return promoCode;
}

public void setPromoCode(String promoCode) {
    this.promoCode = promoCode;
  }
}
```

URLS :  `/search?PromoCode=test` 
        `/search?promoCode=test`
         `/search?promocode=test`

Data binding is working only for the first two requests. I need to make this work case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own Case Insensitive `BeanWrapper` (used for `WebDataBinder` to map parameters from request to fields of Command Object when you are in use of @ModelAttribute) or instead use @RequestBody with data in json/xml format (the recommened way).